# How to make continuous universes using a while loop??

Tags: java, while-loop

This is a homework where we have to make the game of life.  Here is my code

```
Universe u2 = new Universe(Width, Height, ' ');
Universe temp = new Universe(Width, Height, ' ');
//want to write a loop within a loop that goes through every single cell that       contains a character



for (int i=0;i<Width;i++)
{
    for (int j=0; j<Height; j++)
    {
        if (u1.numNeighbors(i, j)>3 || u1.numNeighbors(i, j) <2)
        {
            u2.setPixel(i, j, ' ');
        }
        else if (u1.numNeighbors(i, j) ==3 && u1.getPixel(i, j) == ' ')
        {
            u2.setPixel(i, j, '*');
        }
        else
        {
            u2.setPixel(i,j, '*');
        }
    }

System.out.print(u2);

}
```

So I know that the calculation of the neighbors is working.  I need a way to create continuous universes so the output looks like an animation featured on this [page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life)

The rules can also be found on that page.

I'm thinking I need a while(true) loop but when I implement that it keeps printing the same second universe over and over.

Comment: A `while` loop after the `new Universe` lines around the `for` loops didn't work?  Is that where you put your `while`?

Comment: Ok so I got the while loop part but how do I swap the universes at the end of the loop?  I'm thinking like temp = u2;  u1=temp;   ???

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean goOn=true;
...
...
while(goOn){
    u2=new Universe(...);
    //your double nested for loops
    System.out.print(u2);
    u1=u2;
}
```

Then you can write a keylistener that sets goOn to false whenever you want to quit.